# What do you call the different "versions" of a newspaper's specific issues?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Let's say there is a newspaper called "ACME News".

When they make a new "number" of ACME News, that is called an "issue". As in, issue 1, issue 2, issue 3, etc.

However, for a given day, they might publish several slightly different "versions" of issue 1. For example, the "initial version", the "updated version" and the "final version". I have seen these referred to as "editions", especially as in "final edition".

Is "edition" the right terminology for different "versions" of an issue? Where they have maybe corrected typos, added small updates to existing stories, but don't make any major changes until the next "issue" (which will have a entirely different set of news)?

The problem I have with "edition" is that it seems to overlap with other concepts, such as "Sunday edition" (which should be "Sunday issue" if you ask me), or "British edition", "American edition", "Canadian edition", etc. I don't want to use the word "edition" to refer to more than one concept, to avoid confusion.

So, are different versions of the same issue called "editions", period? Or can they be called "versions"? I'd like to stick fairly closely to established conventions for this.

Comment: This is a stacking or filing problem.  As long as you are clear, it need not matter.  Is this a practical problem you are juggling with, or are you exploring a theoretic question?  If the latter, what do you think about it yourself?

Comment: "Edition" is the term I've heard most often.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there used to be a 'late extra final' (when all the football results were in on a Saturday) edition of the Manchester Evening News.

Comment: Newspapers have editions, not issues. morning edition, afternoon edition, evening editions AND August 1,2010 edition. That last one is for a date of an edition. The date is used like an adjective to refer to a specific editions. Most newspapers only come out once a day. That said, you can also have an edition by country or regional area.

Answer (score 6):

As Hot Licks says "Edition" is used for this.  Here, in today's *New York Times* see "Late Edition" in the upper right.

[image: NYT]

Comment: Right, and it is also the January 30, 2020 edition.

Answer (score 0):

When I was in high school and worked at a small newspaper distributor, the St. Louis Post-Dispatch indicated editions with star (asterisks).  The final edition of the night was the five star "*****".

Answer (score -2):

I learned that they might be called "states"